# Basis for $V$ from eigenvectors of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P_V$ be orthogonal projection on $V$. The linear operator $T:V \to V$ is the restriction of $P_V\circ P_W$ to $V$. Prove that there is an orthonormal basis $ \{\vec{v_1} , \vec{v_2} , \dots 
 , \vec{v_k}\}$ for $V$ of the eigenvectors operator $T$ and $ \{T(\vec{v_1}) , T(\vec{v_2}) , \dots 
 , T(\vec{v_k})\}$ is orthogonal in $W$. Also how nonzero vectors of this set determine the angle between $V$ and $W$?

For the first part, I think we should use Principal axis theorem but I'm not sure. I don't understand the meaning of "angle" here and how can $\vec{v_i}$ be zero? If it's the eigenvector so is nonzero.

Comment: For $T$ to make sense, you need $W \subseteq V$.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam I don't think it's necessarily.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379592902515) could be useful

Comment: Also, "nonzero vectors of this set" refers to $\{T(\vec{v_1}),\dots,T(\vec{v_k})\}$.

Comment: @Maxence1402 Thanks for your help, so we should apply Principal axis theorem? And why $\{T(\vec{v_1}) , T(\vec{v_2}) , \dots 
 , T(\vec{v_k})\}$ lies in $W$?

Comment: @S.H.W I don't know this name of theorem, I googled it but I found nothing that seemed relevant. Maybe I don't know enough. I will answer your second question soon.

Comment: It seems like every vector of $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: But for sure, the image of the basis doesn't lie in $W$, maybe an error in the wording?

Comment: @Maxence1402 Yes, i think it should be $V$.

Comment: @Maxence1402  Anyway, how to prove that set is orthogonal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100637/discussion-between-maxence1402-and-s-h-w).